# Select all tables not containing a value from database in MySql

Tags: mysql

My Database contains tables names as mentioned below and I need the tables not containing underscore(_) values:

```
table1
table1_xyz
table1_xyz_abc

table2
table2_xyz
table2_xyz_abc
```

from above example I need only *talbe1 and table2* to be fetched from the query, the query used to fetch all tables names Not containing underscore(_) values in my DataBaseName:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'DataBaseName' and ( table_name NOT like '%_' OR table_name NOT like '_%' OR table_name NOT like '%_%')
```

but there are no results fetched.

any advice.

Comment: [SQL pattern matching enables you to use `_` to match any single character and `%` to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters).](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

But, some characters have special meaning like:

- \% matches one % character.
- \_ matches one _ character.

.

```
select table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_name NOT like '%\_%'
```

Comment: Brilliant answer,does it work for any special character appending \ for like queries ?

Comment: There are only 2 special characters '%' and '\', if you want to search for table_names containing a percentage sign you will have to write  `table_name like '%\%%'`

Answer (score 0):

use this `select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'DataBaseName' and ( table_name NOT like '%\_' OR table_name NOT like '\_%' OR table_name NOT like '%\_%')`